# When does Jenkins clean up old builds?

Tags: jenkins

I have existing Jenkins (2.90) jobs that are taking up disk space. When I enable the "Discard Old Builds" option I don't see any cleanup going on in the folder on the builds older than 7 days.

When does Jenkins do this cleanup? Or does it only apply for new builds after I apply the setting?

[image: Jenkins discard build option]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the Jenkins documentation:

> Cleanup per project/job is performed after that job runs.
>
> As of v2.221, cleanup will also periodically run using the new Global Build Discarders (even if a job has not recently been run).

[Source](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215549798-Best-Strategy-for-Disk-Space-Management-Clean-Up-Old-Builds).

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I can confirm it cleans up after the job is run.

Comment: Any idea what "periodically" means for the global build discarders though?

Comment: The global cleanup period is set to hourly: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/model/BackgroundGlobalBuildDiscarder.java#L77-L79